# Azure Kubernetes : Spring Batch running on Ubuntu 18.04 is hanging

Tags: linux, kubernetes, spring-batch, ubuntu-18.04, azure-aks

I have a Spring batch 2.1.x application deployed on Azure Kubernetes. Base image is Ubuntu 18.04. I see that the process is hanging at times.

Process flow:

1. 8119 : kubectl command line command to start the bash script
2. 8214 : bash script to start the spring batch
3. 8128 : spring batch application

8128 is hanging with SL state.

[image]

**Note:** I see that the process state is **SL** - interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete) & has pages locked into memory (for real-time and custom IO).

Is this expected? How do I fix this?

**Update:** In this sample, the Execution **Time** : **34:36** is stuck while checking every 2 minutes.
[image]

Comment: Which process in the screenshot do you consider hanging?

Comment: @jordanm - 8128 is hanging with SL state.